# Challenges with useEffect, useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think the way my code is behaving at the present moment it seems that `prepareList` doesn't update in time and thus is undefined and then code gives an error saying filter is not a function, and it returns `finalGroups` as it should if there is no `prepareList.length`. I'm certain that the map inside `prepareList` itself works and there are values (array of objects) behind `removedSubstitutesList` which itself is `useState` array.

As you can see I've tried to prevent this behavior by adding completely irrelevant `useEffect` and `makeWay` and by doing `setWait` inside of it just to make it wait a bit longer to be able to get values to `prepareList`. Also dependencylists are part of trying to get it working somehow to see what is wrong.

**My question is:** is my reduce function itself wrong and thus it doesn't work or if it is indeed the problem of `useState`, multiple renderings etc. so that reducer function runs too early without a value or is there something else that I haven't noticed.

This code is a part of a bigger set and this part is supposed to gather, process and lift up prepared data to the main app component for it to use. Sendpressed here is a buttonclick and liftSubstitutes and liftSubstituteGroups are callbacks to send data to main app component.

Hopefully I've managed to be clear enough to follow through and if not I'll try my best to guide you through it. Any suggestions are welcomed, thanks in advance.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const makeWay = () => {
      setWait('a');
    };
    makeWay();
  }, [sendPressed, finalGroups, removedSubstitutesList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const liftFinalData = () => {
      const prepareList = removedSubstitutesList.map(item => item.email);
      const finalResults = !prepareList.length
        ? finalGroups
        : prepareList.reduce(
            (results, filter) => results.filter(filter),
            finalGroups[0].data
          );

      liftSubstitutes(Substitutes || 0);
      liftSubstituteGroups(finalResults || 0);
    };
    liftFinalData();
  }, [sendPressed, finalGroups, wait]);
```

Comment: How are you getting prepareList? If you are trying to initialize it once, the easiest way wound be to put the function within useState. ie useState(() => {...return ... })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, the issue is with `filter()` in `reduce()`.

So [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) takes 2 arguments:

1. The first is the accumulator, in your case `finalGroups[0].data` which looks okay.
2. The second is the current value from the iteration - `filter` variable.

So in your case I guess the issue is that as the error message states that `filter` is not a function. Technically `filter` in this case one element from `prepareList` array.

For [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you need to pass a function which return `true` or `false` value, from the documentation:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Think about the following solution:

```
(results, prepareListElem) => results.filter(element => {
   var passTest = false;

   // the logic to implement for passTest

   return passTest;
})
```

Giving one working example how `reduce()` and `filter()` are working:

```js
const array = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Jane'}];
const result = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
   acc.push({
      ...cur,
      age: 12
   });

   return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);

const filtered = result.filter(e => e.name.indexOf('a') !== -1);

console.log(filtered);
```

In my example, we have elements in an array where all the object has `name` property. We are trying to extend with `age`. At the end we are filtering where the `name` property contains character `a`.

I hope this helps and clarifies where you have issues!

Comment: Thank you, your answer did help me in cracking down the problem. In the end I didn't solve it like suggested but it led me to right direction in how things work and in the end I managed to come up with a fitting solution. I have to mention that the problem was both, a certain value being undefined on initial render and problems with filtering. First was solved with if clauses so that it doesn't get to check the value too early and with your ideas I was able to make working solution to filtering problem. So, all in all, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @axordahaxor Awesome, happy to help!